# Create a Salesforce report to track mail merges

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-development

I am looking to create a salesforce report on mail merges done on daily basis.

I am not sure on which object I am suppose to start.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ooo, interesting! It's not one of things covered by [Event Monitoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm).

I don't think you can do much. Maybe post at https://ideas.salesforce.com/ ?
If you use some custom package for mail merge (weaver? conga? formstack?) they might have their own statistics.

If you're after standard email templates - best you can do is query [EmailTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm) daily, store results (especially `TimesUsed`) in some helper object? From what I remember it counts only if human used the template, automations don't count.

If you're after real mail merge, ancient feature for creating Word/Excel etc - tough. It's not actively developed (it understands Word 2007, no guarantees about higher versions for example). Maybe you'll be able to do something based on Tasks created during merge?